# Running application with a flag in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What is a proper way to run an application with any flag in Docker?

I have tried this:

**Dockerfile**

```
# ...
CMD ["-flag_name='value"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

But my go app cannot see that flag in `main.go`:

```
f := flag.String("flag_name", "default_value", "")
```

And `f` always equal to `"default_value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, only the `CMD` can work, providing `entrypoint` is helpful when you want to have some custom logic to prepare container or you when you want to pass `flag` at run time, where you are trying to set `flag` at `build` time.

```
CMD ["./app","-flag_name=value"]
```

While providing flag at runtime then entrypoint can make sense

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

then

```
docker run -it --rm myapp -flag_name=value
```

BTW combination of entrypoint and CMD should also work

```
entrypoint ["/app/hello"]
CMD ["-word=value"]
```